# ios NSKeyedArchiver releasing = bad access

Tags: ios, custom-controls, release, nskeyedarchiver

I have an noob problem and I would like you yo point me in the right direction. Basicly I have a custom class which implements the copying protocol. However when I save the class during execution the custom class i released and I get a bad access. I can see in instruments that the retain count is -2. I save the custom class with the following method:

```
-(void)storeDataInFile:(NSString*)dataFileName DataArray:(NSArray*)dataToStore 
{
    //Get the path
    NSString *path = [self pathToDocumentsForDataFile:dataFileName];
    //Archive the file
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:dataToStore toFile:path];
}
```

Is I use the method sor saving a array with strings it works flawless. What should I look deeper into regarding my custom class?

Regards

Comment: You should put enter your answer and select is as correct rather than putting it along with the question.

Comment: I have added it to the the text but I cant seem to find a way to create an answer

Comment: Try reading the faq.  Its pretty easy to answer; people do it every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soved this issue, however I only provided the solution in a comment which apprantly has been deleted. So I just wanted to post the answer which indicates it was a noob mistake.
From an eralier test implementation I had the following method in the class

```
    - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return self;
}

//retain is counted up
- (id)retain {
    return self;
}

- (unsigned)retainCount {
    return UINT_MAX;
}
```

These methods ruined my retain count :)